# How to add numbers to overflow containing images

Tags: javascript, css, numbers, overflow, slideshow

I am working on a one pager.  I am trying to showcase the number of images shown in the overflow.

The overflow contains only images (easiest way I know is to add a vertical scroll to a sequence of images). The images are within a div and I am using the CSS-grid system to layout the whole page.

Is it possible to make this using CSS or javascript?

Hope this makes sense.

I would like to add a numbering system in the form of 4/14, so that as the user scrolls he can see how far down the set of images he is.

Comment: Have you tried this out for yourself yet? If so can you link the code?

Comment: No I havent I have no idea where to start in order to do that. here is my code https://codepen.io/Design_Lover/pen/OKQyKM